# Enterprise WSDL and polymorphism

Tags: soap-api, soap, c#, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

We're using the Enterprise WSDL to write a service that will be run from our server and sync data to Salesforce. We're using C# to do this.
I have several functions that perform SOAP operations on lists of generic sObjects such as

```
public void upsertSObjects(List<sObject> sobjs, string externalIdField){
    ...
}
```

My custom objects are defined properly in the class generated by the WSDL. For example:

```
public partial class MyCustomObject__c : sObject {
    ...
}
```

Following the rules of polymorphism, one would expect that I would be able to do the following:

```
List<MyCustomObject__c> myList = new List<MyCustomObject__c>();
//populate the list with records
upsertSObjects(myList, "ExtId__c");
```

However, I get a compilation error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<namespace.MyCustomObject__c>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<namespace.sObject>'
```

Comment: I've voted to close this. It is a scenario specific to C# rather than Salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the in-variant vs co-variant scenario on Generic Lists. See [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

That's the computer science explanation, but I find an example easier to work through.

Let's say C# *did* let you pass your List in to the upsertSObjects method like you proposed.

```
List<MyCustomObject__c> myList = new List<MyCustomObject__c>();
//populate the list with records
upsertSObjects(myList, "ExtId__c");
```

Now `upsertSObjects` has the `sobjs` argument that it thinks is a `List<sObject>`. That's all fine, **unless** the upsertSObjects tries to add something else to the `sobjs` List. Something that is or inherits from `sObject` but is not a `MyCustomObject__c`. Now we have a problem, because you can't do that to `myList` without breaking the generic type is is storing.

Because of that scenario C# will stop you at compile time.

A couple of possible solutions:

1. Change the signature of upsertSObjects to `public void upsertSObjects(IEnumerable<sObject> sobjs, string externalIdField){}`. IEnumerable doesn't have an add/insert method so the problem goes away.
2. Change `myList` to be a `List<sObject>`. Now the underlying type can old anything that inherits form it.

See also:

- [Cannot convert from `List<DerivedClass>` to `List<BaseClass>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16966961/54026)